# How to create json from javascript with this structure

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I am trying to write data to firebase realtime database. I am following the video examples and they show some syntax like this for their json.

[image: From Firebase Videos]

My example is somewhat similar to this. I have orders and books in those orders.
I am trying to create a table like EventAttendees for books tied to order
I thin i want "fm" to equal the order number and then i would have a list of books. I can't figure out how to dynamically name fm to be the order number.

```
<pre><code>Book: {
"booksArr": [
"9490455",
{
  "name": "Baby's Very First Lift-the-Flap Peek-a-Boo At the Zoo (BD)",
  "sku": "52367",
  "price": "9.99",
  "qty": "1",
  "extPrice": "9.99"
},
{
  "name": "Peek Inside the Farm (BD)",
  "sku": "34424",
  "price": "11.99",
  "qty": "1",
  "extPrice": "11.99"
}</code></pre>
```

Where it says booksArr i would think i would want the orderNumber

```
<pre><code>
var books = {};
books.booksArr = [orderNumber];

do {
...
let book = {
      name:bookName,
      sku:sku,
      price:price,
      qty:qty,
      extPrice:extPrice
    }  
      books.booksArr.push(book)
...
} while (exit == false);
</code></pre>
```

Any help would be apricated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use it like an associative array `books[orderNumber].push(book)` - you will have to initialze that array first with `if (!books.hasOwnProperty(orderNumber)) books[ordernumber]=[];`

```
var books = {};
 
do {
...
let book = {
      name:bookName,
      sku:sku,
      price:price,
      qty:qty,
      extPrice:extPrice
    }  
    if (!books.hasOwnProperty(orderNumber)) books[ordernumber]=[];
    books[orderNumber].push(book)
...
} while (exit == false);
```

Comment: This is returning me an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined. I tried setting books to both {} and [].

Comment: I updated my answer, forgot to initialize the array :)

Answer (score 0):

Take  JSON and parse() it and set it equal to data.  The use `const  json = JSON.stringify(data.eventAttendees);`